# Хостинг в Америке или Европе?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, vds

Как вы считаете, в какой стране/городе лучше физически расположить сервер для сайта, ориентированного на англоязычную аудиторию. Сайт не нацелен на конкретную страну и континент (проект с уроками по языкам программирования). Где его лучше расположить - в Европе или Америке, чтобы получить наиболее низкий пинг?

Comment: Роман, вопрос немного некорректный и не соответствует тематике сайта, поэтому вас кто-то уже начинает минусовать. Ваш вопрос не несет однозначного ответа и скорее всего породит бессмысленные споры или кучу предложений попробовать "вот этот класный хостинг". Можно заглянуть в раздел справки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help в пункт "Как задавать вопросы", он поможет в следующий раз не делать подобных вопросов

Comment: Выбор хостинга не зависит от содержания сайта или вашего потенциального посетителя, он скорее определяется конъюнктурой и законодательством страны (например, если вы хотите располагать на сайте материалы, недопустимые в вашей стране, то, разумеется, хоститься лучше зарубежом), а также вашими личными предпочтениями к хостингу (наличие русскоязычной поддержки или бонусные акции, например). Наверняка, самым правильным ответом на ваш вопрос будет - выбирайте любой, на какой хватит денег.

Comment: Уважаемые минусующие, вместо того, чтобы лепить человеку отрицательные оценки, лучше бы разъяснили что к чему, чтобы в будущем он не повторял подобным ошибок. Не будем уподобляться англоязычному SO и "избивать" новичков

Answer (score 2):

Как понимаю, вас интересует низкий пинг для вашей потенциальной аудитории. По месту расположения серверов тут все полностью зависит от того, где именно вы будете продвигать проект.

Если в Европе, то рекомендую обратить внимание на хостинговые компании в Нидерландах (Хаарлем, Амстердам), Великобритании (Лондон), Ирландии (Дублин) или Германии (Франкфурт, Гамбург). В этих городах располагаются крупнейшие узлы обмена трафиком, поэтому они обеспечиваю наиболее низкий пинг для всей Европы. Для проектов, ориентированных как на Европу, так и на Россию хороший пинг можно получить из Финляндии (например, https://www.upcloud.com/) или Санкт-Петербурга.

Если в США, то рекомендую Сан-Франциско или Нью-Йорк. Если интересует аудитория как в Штатах, так в Европе - рекомендую завести CDN, чем держать сервер где-то в одном месте. Пинг через океанический кабель достаточно большой (до 100-120 мс), что ощутимо затормозит загрузку контента (особенно при первом обращении к DNS, а также при наличии SSL).

P.S. Для Европы и США VDS настоятельно не рекомендую, лучше используйте облачный хостинг - будет намного выгоднее и более удобно в масштабировании. Например, в той же Голландии есть отличная компания Scaleway (https://www.scaleway.com/), отлично подходит для размещения сайтов, ориентированных на Западную Европу. Также Голландия имеет лояльное законодательство ко многим интернет-проектам, которые гарантированно подвергнутся ограничениям в других странах.